# Is there a way to know if a 50's immigrant became an USA citizen?

Tags: united-states, immigration

My grandfather and father (both deceased many decades ago) immigrated to USA from Cuba in the 50's, returning to Cuba in 1959 to try to sell all their properties but they never could return back to USA. All I have is a scan of my father's immigrant card. Is there a way to find out if he became US citizens? So if he did, I could be an US citizen by direct descendance? Does this document provides me any special shortcut in terms of migrating to the USA?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a form [here](https://www.uscis.gov/g-1041) which you submit to USCIS – immigrated not before 1906, not for a living person. However, to apply for citizenship, one must have been a permanent resident for 5 years, so given the date on the card (and assuming your father did not marry a US citizen), he could not have been naturalized before departure in 1959.

Comment: It's possible that the minimum residency requirements were different in the 1950s, but it does seem unlikely that they naturalized.  Still, if I were in Aram Alvarez's shoes, I'd want to know what the requirements were at the time.  It's possible that the grandfather married and naturalized before returning to Cuba.  Depending on the father's age, this might have resulted in the acquisition of US citizenship.